# Printing nested json values does not work with ExtJS

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs5

I get a json response string from my webservice in this format:

```
{
   "id":"1", 
   "name":"Steve", 
   "age":"50", 
   "items":[
        {"itemType":"item1"}, 
        {"itemType":"item2"}
   ]
}
```

I have a specified "json" as my `reader` in my store, but it seems it cannot parse the nested json parts:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Persons',{
     extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
     model: 'MyApp.model.Person',
     storeId: 'PersonStore',
     proxy: {
        type: 'ajax', 
        url: 'http://localhost:80/index.php?person=get', 
        reader: {
           type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
```

When I select a row in the grid I can fetch the values like:

```
var record = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
console.log(record[0].get('name'));  // prints "Steve"
```

But fetching the `items` does not work:

```
console.log(record[0].get('items')[0]);  // prints "Undefined"
```

How can I print the items of the person?

**EDIT:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Person',{
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     idProperty: 'id',
     fields: [
         {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
         {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
         {name: 'age', type: 'int'},
     ],
     hasMany: {
         model: 'MyApp.model.Item',
         name: 'items',
         associationKey: 'items'    
     } 
});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.Item',{
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model', 
     fields: [
         {
             name: 'id', 
             type: 'int'
         },
         {
             name: 'itemType', 
             type: 'string'
         }
     ],
     belongsTo: 'MyApp.model.Person'     
});
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Persons',{
     extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
     model: 'MyApp.model.Person',
     storeId: 'PersonStore',
     proxy: {
        type: 'ajax', 
        url: 'http://localhost:80/index.php?person=get', 
        reader: {
           type: 'jsonpersonreader'
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.reader.JsonPersonReader',{
     extend: 'Ext.data.reader.Json',
     alias: 'reader.jsonpersonreader',
     getResponseData: function(response) {

         return JSON.parse(response.responseText);
     }
});
```

Comment: Extjs4? What does the model look like?

Comment: It is ExtJS 5. Look at my edit above for the model.

Comment: Try `record[0].items()` for getting the items store.

Comment: The store is empty. `console.log(record[0].items().count())` prints `0`. Why is it empty when other fields exist?

Comment: @CD..: Look at my second edit. Am I supposed to create my own Json reader to parse the json response correctly?

Answer (score 0):

¿Did you tried not to use the "hasMany" configuration? and instead do something like this:

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.model.Person',{
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     idProperty: 'id',
     fields: [
         {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
         {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
         {name: 'age', type: 'int'},
         {name: 'items', type:'auto'}
     ]
});
```

And use:

**record[0].get('items')[0].id**

or

**record[0].items[0].id**